# R studio-style outline for VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

As per the title, I am looking for something akin to R Studio's outline pane in VS Code. Specifically, in R Studio, I can set breakpoints in a script using something like:

> # section 1 (load packages) ----
> # section 2 (read data) ----
> # section 3 (run analyses) ----

Etc., which then populates a clickable outline pane.

In VS Code, the outline pane just shows a list of all symbols, which is useful, but not quite what I'm looking for. Similarly, Jupyter notebooks have a TOCs extension for what I am looking for, but I would like something that I can use in VS Code with native .py files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
   # region ---  
   code  
   # endregion
```

in combination with custom keyboard shortcut and Region Viewer extension solves my problem